# What is ResourceRegister doing behind the scenes?

Tags: curated-data, wolfram-cloud

For practicing good data hygiene, designing system architecture, searching, debugging etc it is useful to know what underlying changes are being made to your system when functions like `ResourceRegister` are used.

Some interactions with WRI folk indicate that registration occurs in `PersistentObject`'s that point to actual storage locations of the full content/meta-data along with documentation statements like:

> If the resource is registered in a "local" `PersistenceLocation`, the resource content will be cached locally with`LocalCache[resource]`

but take the following sequence:

```
pl = PersistenceLocation["Local"];
ro = ResourceObject[<|"Name" -> "Ten Primes",
    "ResourceType" -> "Data", "Content" -> Prime[Range[10]]|>];
ror = ResourceRegister[ro, pl];
pl // InputForm

(* PersistenceLocation["Local", 
 "file:///Users/ronaldmonson/Library/Wolfram/Objects/Persistence", 
 Hold[Persistence`Data`a29338699036471582931$7]] *)
```

where there does not seem to be any change in the `PersistenceLocation` directory while the data itself seems to be stored in an ".../Objects/Resources/..." directory (and within a "metadata" directory?)

```
ro["ResourceLocations"]

(* {LocalObject["file:///Users/ronaldmonson/Library/Wolfram/Objects/Resources/185/185d5e50-fcba-4e88-9082-cd59809b3a8b"]} *)
```

Where does `LocalCache` come into it as `$CacheBaseDirectory` appears unmodified?

How does future invocations of `ResourceObject[Ten Primes]` find the named resource?

Further, how is it updated from corresponding cloud resources?

Finally, on removing the resource

```
ResourceRemove@ror
```

there is lingering cruft?

```
FileExistsQ["/Users/ronaldmonson/Library/Wolfram/Objects/Resources/185/"]
FileExistsQ["/Users/ronaldmonson/Library/Wolfram/Objects/Resources/searchdata/185/"]

(* 
True
True
*)
```

Is there then, a good mental model of what `ResourceRegister` is doing internally including what files are being created/modified/updated/searched?